# Como pausar y reanudar un setInterval en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, botón, eventos, setinterval

Tengo este código:

```
tiempo = 60;
function restarTiempo() {
    tiempo--;
    document.getElementById('tiempo').innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;Tiempo: ' + tiempo;
    if (tiempo == 0) {
        alert('Perdiste');
        location.href = '';
    }
}
setInterval(restarTiempo, 1000);
```

Pero quiero que cuando se le de clic a un botón el tiempo se pare. Que debo hacer?

Ya que para los botones tengo este código:

```
document.getElementById('pau').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('pau').classList.add('dnone');
    document.getElementById('rea').classList.remove('dnone');
});


document.getElementById('rea').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById('rea').classList.add('dnone');
    document.getElementById('pau').classList.remove('dnone');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar esto :

```
//Creamos un intervalo 
let intervalo;

tiempo = 60;
function restarTiempo() {
    tiempo--;
    document.getElementById('tiempo').innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;Tiempo: ' + tiempo;
    if (tiempo == 0) {
        alert('Perdiste');
        location.href = '';
    }
}
//Creamos una funcion para iniciar el temporizador
function startTiempo(){
    intervalo = setInterval(restarTiempo , 1000);
}
//Creamos una para pararlo
function stopTiempo(){
    clearInterval(intervalo);
}
```

Luego llamamos a la funcion startTiempo() y el temporizador comenzara , cuando lo desees detener simplemente usar stopTiempo() y el temporizador parara.
Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.